# sup is bounded or not?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The sup is as following:

$c_f = sup_{x,s\in D} \ f(y) - f(x) - (y-x)^Tb$

where $y=x+\alpha(s-x)$, $\alpha \in (0,1 )$ is constant and $b$ is a constant vector. $D$ is a convex compact set and $f:R^n\rightarrow R$ is a convex function. Is $c_f$ bounded? I think it is because everything in the above equation is bounded ($y$ is on the line segment between $x$ and $s$.). Please help me to prove or disprove that $c_f$ is bounded. Thanks:)

Comment: The function is continuous and you are taking the $\sup$ over the compact set $D \times D$.

Comment: @copper.hat what's your point?

Comment: Let $\phi(x,s)$ be the function 'inside' the $\sup$. It is continuous. Hence $\{ \phi(x,s) \}_{x,s \in D}$ is compact and as a consequence, bounded.